# HIve Related date conversion

Tags: sql, date, hive

I am facing issue while trying to add one year to the current timestamp.
I was able to add the year to the current timestamp but the timestamp is not coming with the result.
Any help would be a great support.

I am tring this select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());

Comment: There is not enough information in your question for an answer. What have you tried and how has it not worked? Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on how to ask a good question to get better results.

Comment: Can you show query how you are adding one year ?

Comment: select current_timestamp() + interval '1' year

Comment: I am Sorry if my query is not clear please dont feel bad about that ,as I am new to this forum and it was my first query regarding my requirement.

Comment: Let me brief you all what has happened I have a query which is in sql server code and i need to convert that in hive sql and I tried various ways but i couldn't get desired results.

Comment: What I had tried is mentioned below select current_timestamp() +  '1'   year ,    select date_add(from_unixtimes(unix_timestamp()), 12) ,it is giving me the next year same date but timestamp is missing. I need date exactly same as today if today is 2020-04-25 12:18:00 i need 2021-04-25 12:18:00 ,this is my requirement. In sql server the code is dateadd(M,+12,getdate()). please share your comments

Answer (score 1):

If you want a timestamp one year later than now, you can do date arithmetics as follows:

```
select current_timestamp() + interval '1' year
```

Comment: Dear it is still throwing error ,the syntax near 1 has some issue ,i tried the other way before but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using hive udf.

```java
    package com.practice;

    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;


    public class addYearWithTimestamp extends UDF{

        private  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

        public String evaluate(String t, int year) throws ParseException{
            long time=formatter.parse(t.toString()).getTime();
            java.sql.Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(ts);
            cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            ts.setTime(cal.getTime().getTime()); 
            return ts.toString();
        }

    }
```

After creating addYearWithTimestamp.jar, register it into hive and create udf:

```
ADD JAR /home/cloudera/Desktop/addYearWithTimestamp.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION addYear as 'com.practice.addYearWithTimestamp';
```

Use that udf :

```
hive> SELECT addYear(current_timestamp,1);
OK
2021-04-25 08:22:17.948
Time taken: 0.083 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Hive supports interval arithmetic since 1.2 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9792